# Open firebug in right side

Tags: firebug

I've used Widerbug (http://www.command-tab.com/2008/01/19/widerbug-widescreen-firebug/) to open Firebug in the right side of the browser instead at the bottom. Recently I updated my FF and now widerbug doesn't work. I installed the latest version of Firebug, but that didn't help. How can I attach Firebug to the right side of my browser?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Firebug has a setting called "UI Location". In your current Firebug panel, click the bug icon and you'll see this setting. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Similar to Firebug, there is an icon in the top right of Chrome Developer Tools that you click and it offers three Dock side options: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYeYM.png

Comment: It would help to mention to press `alt` to look that menu bar, because from a primarily chrome user perspective i sometimes forget, and look confusingly in the ff 3-bar preference menu, to no avail, which alone  irritates, however at that point, i still have to have to finally realize its "somewhere" up in the top menu, and how to open that,... If you can add to your answer it would be helpful :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Simpler and faster solution:

1. Look to very top right for the Minimise, New Window, and Close buttons.
2. Right click on any these and select right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of anything like Widerbug, but you could open it in a new window and just place it where you want, at least until you find a better solution or Widerbug is updated.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Developer Tools you can do this similarly by clicking the vertical dotted menu icon in the top right of the Developer Tools, and selecting one of the Dock side options (undock into separate window, dock to bottom, dock to right). Here is a screenshot:

[image: screen shot]